# How can I use tcpdump to see capture file?

Tags: python, tcpdump

I have captured packet In the Internet by using
 sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -w FILENAME.pcap
I want to see capture file with tcpdump,I have used : 
tcpdump -qns 0 -A -r FILENAME.pcap
The capture file looks terrible , How can I make it prettier?
Thanks
Sarah

Answer (score 2):

> The capture file looks terrible , How can I make it prettier?

Pass the `-v` flag to tcpdump, to get more verbose output?  Read it with [Wireshark or TShark](https://www.wireshark.org)?  The default output of tcpdump looks the way it's written to look, which can be a bit cryptic; tcpdump with `-v`, and Wireshark/TShark, may be a bit more verbose.